# Oracle crashing on CentOS

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g, crash, shutdown

Here is alert_XE.log:

```
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Tue Dec 29 20:37:36 2015
Process W000 died, see its trace file
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process W000 died, see its trace file
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Tue Dec 29 20:37:43 2015
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process W000 died, see its trace file
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Process J000 died, see its trace file
kkjcre1p: unable to spawn jobq slave process 
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:
Tue Dec 29 20:37:48 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Tue Dec 29 20:37:48 2015
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_psp0_23022.trc:
ORA-27157: OS post/wait facility removed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semop failed with status: 43
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwwait1
Tue Dec 29 20:37:48 2015
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_q000_23151.trc:
ORA-27157: OS post/wait facility removed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semop failed with status: 43
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwwait1
PSP0 (ospid: 23022): terminating the instance due to error 27157
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Error occured while spawning process J000; error = 27157
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
Instance terminated by PSP0, pid = 23022
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_psp0_23022.trc:
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semctl failed with status: 43
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwrm1
ORA-27157: OS post/wait facility removed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semop failed with status: 43
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwwait1
Tue Dec 29 20:37:48 2015
Instance termination got error 27120 from SGA destruction.
  Error cleared. Process exiting.
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =35
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 200
  sessions                 = 324
  memory_target            = 1G
  control_files            = "/var/oracle/oradata/control.dbf"
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "/var/oracle/oracle_fra"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 20G
  undo_management          = "AUTO"
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=XEXDB)"
  shared_servers           = 4
  job_queue_processes      = 4
  audit_file_dest          = "/u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/adump"
  db_name                  = "XE"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "/u01/app/oracle"
Tue Dec 29 20:37:48 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=8761 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:49 2015
PSP0 started with pid=3, OS id=8763 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
VKTM started with pid=4, OS id=8765 
VKTM running at (100ms) precision 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
GEN0 started with pid=5, OS id=8769 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
DIAG started with pid=6, OS id=8771 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
DBRM started with pid=7, OS id=8773 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=8775 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=8777 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=8779 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=8781 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=8783 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=8785 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=8787 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=8789 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=8791 
starting up 4 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE not set in environment. It is recommended
that ORACLE_BASE be set in the environment
Reusing ORACLE_BASE from an earlier startup = /u01/app/oracle
Tue Dec 29 20:37:50 2015
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 2780912478
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Tue Dec 29 20:37:54 2015
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
Started redo scan
Completed redo scan
 read 47 KB redo, 26 data blocks need recovery
Started redo application at
 Thread 1: logseq 89, block 2488
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 2 Seq 89 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /var/oracle/oracle_fra/XE/onlinelog/o1_mf_2_c80m1spv_.log
Completed redo application of 0.03MB
Completed crash recovery at
 Thread 1: logseq 89, block 2582, scn 683264
 26 data blocks read, 26 data blocks written, 47 redo k-bytes read
LGWR: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES
Tue Dec 29 20:37:54 2015
ARC0 started with pid=23, OS id=8863 
ARC0: Archival started
LGWR: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES COMPLETE
ARC0: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 90 (thread open)
Thread 1 opened at log sequence 90
  Current log# 1 seq# 90 mem# 0: /var/oracle/oracle_fra/XE/onlinelog/o1_mf_1_c80m1svh_.log
Successful open of redo thread 1
SMON: enabling cache recovery
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
ARC1 started with pid=24, OS id=8865 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
ARC2 started with pid=25, OS id=8867 
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
ARC3 started with pid=26, OS id=8869 
ARC1: Archival started
ARC2: Archival started
ARC1: Becoming the 'no FAL' ARCH
ARC1: Becoming the 'no SRL' ARCH
ARC2: Becoming the heartbeat ARCH
Archived Log entry 94 added for thread 1 sequence 89 ID 0xa5bd2e68 dest 1:
[8861] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:375718384 end:375718404 diff:20 (0 seconds)
Verifying file header compatibility for 11g tablespace encryption..
Verifying 11g file header compatibility for tablespace encryption completed
SMON: enabling tx recovery
Database Characterset is AL32UTF8
Opening with Resource Manager plan: INTERNAL_PLAN_XE 
Starting background process VKRM
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
VKRM started with pid=27, OS id=8871 
replication_dependency_tracking turned off (no async multimaster replication found)
Starting background process QMNC
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
QMNC started with pid=28, OS id=8873 
Completed: ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Tue Dec 29 20:37:55 2015
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 20480 MB is 32.96% used. This is a
user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
Starting background process CJQ0
Tue Dec 29 20:37:56 2015
CJQ0 started with pid=30, OS id=8887 
ARC3: Archival started
ARC0: STARTING ARCH PROCESSES COMPLETE
Tue Dec 29 20:42:56 2015
Starting background process SMCO
Tue Dec 29 20:42:56 2015
SMCO started with pid=22, OS id=9026
```

Here is /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/XE_cjq0_23146.trc:

```
2015-12-29 20:37:33.571273 :80EE0F32:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572112 :80EE0FD5:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572123 :80EE0FD7:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572232 :80EE0FD8:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572232 :80EE0FD9:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572237 :80EE0FDA:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572261 :80EE0FDD:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:34.572261 :80EE0FDE:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:35.573219 :80EE101E:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:35.573244 :80EE1021:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:35.573345 :80EE102A:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:35.573346 :80EE102B:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:36.575791 :80EE1060:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:36.575821 :80EE1063:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:36.575822 :80EE1064:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576197 :80EE1114:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576207 :80EE1116:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576304 :80EE1117:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[2] comment=[KSB action for X-instance calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576305 :80EE1118:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[18] comment=[KSB action for ksbxic() calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576305 :80EE1119:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[104] comment=[Scumnt mount lock]
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576306 :80EE111A:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[105] comment=[Poll system events broadcast channel]
2015-12-29 20:37:37.576307 :80EE111B:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[332] comment=[Check for async messages from other instances]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577049 :80EE1145:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[2] comment=[KSB action for X-instance calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577051 :80EE1146:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[18] comment=[KSB action for ksbxic() calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577051 :80EE1147:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[104] comment=[Scumnt mount lock]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577052 :80EE1148:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[105] comment=[Poll system events broadcast channel]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577053 :80EE1149:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[332] comment=[Check for async messages from other instances]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577056 :80EE114A:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[0] comment=[Monitor Cleanup]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577057 :80EE114B:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[3] comment=[KSB action for bast checking]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577057 :80EE114C:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[205] comment=[Job Queue Timout]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577353 :80EE114D:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577354 :80EE114E:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577356 :80EE114F:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577383 :80EE1152:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:38.577383 :80EE1153:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578156 :80EE1183:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578167 :80EE1185:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578264 :80EE1186:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578265 :80EE1187:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578270 :80EE1188:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578288 :80EE118B:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:39.578289 :80EE118C:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:40.579227 :80EE1242:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:40.579248 :80EE1245:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:40.579349 :80EE1246:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:40.579350 :80EE1247:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:41.580367 :80EE128B:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:41.580389 :80EE128E:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:41.580389 :80EE128F:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581155 :80EE12C6:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581167 :80EE12C8:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581268 :80EE12C9:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581269 :80EE12CA:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581274 :80EE12CB:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581301 :80EE12CE:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:42.581301 :80EE12CF:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582151 :80EE1372:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582160 :80EE1374:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582259 :80EE1375:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[2] comment=[KSB action for X-instance calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582259 :80EE1376:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[18] comment=[KSB action for ksbxic() calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582260 :80EE1377:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[104] comment=[Scumnt mount lock]
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582260 :80EE1378:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[105] comment=[Poll system events broadcast channel]
2015-12-29 20:37:43.582261 :80EE1379:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[332] comment=[Check for async messages from other instances]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583036 :80EE13BA:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[2] comment=[KSB action for X-instance calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583040 :80EE13BB:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[18] comment=[KSB action for ksbxic() calls]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583040 :80EE13BC:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[104] comment=[Scumnt mount lock]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583041 :80EE13BD:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[105] comment=[Poll system events broadcast channel]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583041 :80EE13BE:db_trace:ksb.c@1763:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (interrupt action) : acnum=[332] comment=[Check for async messages from other instances]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583045 :80EE13BF:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[0] comment=[Monitor Cleanup]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583045 :80EE13C0:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[3] comment=[KSB action for bast checking]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583045 :80EE13C1:db_trace:ksb.c@1789:ksbcti(): [10254:29:87] KSBCTI: (CJQ0) : (timeout action)   : acnum=[205] comment=[Job Queue Timout]
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583308 :80EE13C2:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:44.583309 :80EE13C3:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:45.582202 :80EE13F6:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:45.582227 :80EE13F9:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:45.582228 :80EE13FA:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583172 :80EE14A4:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583183 :80EE14A6:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583283 :80EE14A7:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583283 :80EE14A8:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583289 :80EE14A9:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583313 :80EE14AC:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:46.583314 :80EE14AD:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584185 :80EE14E0:db_trace:ksb.c@3146:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: end callback function called
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584197 :80EE14E2:db_trace:ksb.c@3189:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: done with active = 0
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584309 :80EE14E3:db_trace:ksb.c@2906:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: enter for server = 2555179904
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584310 :80EE14E4:db_trace:ksb.c@2938:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: obtained PR enqueue
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584315 :80EE14E5:db_trace:ksb.c@2996:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: called start callback function
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584343 :80EE14E8:db_trace:ksb.c@3079:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: oracle executable name validated proc=[J000]
2015-12-29 20:37:47.584343 :80EE14E9:db_trace:ksb.c@3082:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: starting to wait for 12000 seconds
2015-12-29 20:37:48.592273 :80EE153A:db_trace:ksb.c@3132:ksbsrv(): [10254:29:87] KSBSRV: unexpected error during process spawn OER(27157)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trace Bucket Dump End: default bucket for process 29 (osid: 23146, CJQ0)
error 27157 detected in background process
OPIRIP: Uncaught error 447. Error stack:
ORA-00447: fatal error in background process
ORA-27157: OS post/wait facility removed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semop failed with status: 43
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwwait1
```

I suspect it crashes when making automated online backup via this script:

```
user=`/usr/bin/whoami`
group=`/usr/bin/groups $user | grep dba`
if test -z "$group"; then
   if [ -f /usr/bin/zenity ]
   then
        /usr/bin/zenity --error --text="$user must be in the DBA OS group to backup the database."
   elif [ -f /usr/bin/kdialog ]
   then
        /usr/bin/kdialog --error "$user must be in the DBA OS group to backup the database."
   elif [ -f /usr/bin/xterm ]
   then
       echo "Operation failed. $user must be in the DBA OS group to backup the database."
       echo -n "Press any key to exit"
       read userinp
   fi
   exit 0
fi

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

TMPDIR=/tmp
rman_normlog=${TMPDIR}/rman_normlog$$.log

#Fix a logfile for current, previous run and spfile2init.ora
sqlplus /nolog > $rman_normlog << EOF
   connect / as sysdba;
   set echo off;
   set head off;
   set serveroutput on;
   set linesize 515;
   declare
      l1 varchar2(512);
   begin
      l1 := dbms_backup_restore.normalizeFilename('spfile2init.ora');
      dbms_output.put_line('-----------------');
      dbms_output.put_line(l1);
      dbms_output.put_line('-----------------');
   end;
   /
EOF
rman_spfile2init=`grep "spfile2init.ora$" $rman_normlog`
rm -f $rman_normlog

rman_backup_current=/var/oracle/ora_backup_script/oxe_backup_current.log
rman_backup_prev=/var/oracle/ora_backup_script/oxe_backup_previous.log

#Choose a temporary log for this run
rman_backup=${TMPDIR}/rman_backup$$.log
echo XE Backup Log > $rman_backup

#Check if flash recovery area is enabled
rman_fra=${TMPDIR}/rman_fra$$.log
sqlplus /nolog > $rman_fra << EOF
   connect / as sysdba;
   set head off;
   set echo off;
   set trimspool on;
   set linesize 512;
   select '$' || count(*) || '$' from v\$parameter
    where upper(name)='DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST'
      and value is not null;
EOF
fra=`grep "^$.*$" $rman_fra`
rm -f $rman_fra

if [ X$fra = X\$1\$ ]; then
   failed=false;
else
   failed=true
   errstr="flash recovery area is not enabled"
fi;

if [ $failed = 'false' ] ; then
   #Check the mode of database
   rman_log_mode=${TMPDIR}/rman_log_mode$$.log
   sqlplus /nolog > $rman_log_mode << EOF
      connect / as sysdba;
      set head off;
      set echo off;
      set trimspool on;
      set linesize 512;
      select '$' || log_mode || '$' from v\$database;
EOF
   mode=`grep "^$.*$" $rman_log_mode`
   rm -f $rman_log_mode

   case $mode in
      \$ARCHIVELOG\$)
      echo "Doing online backup of the database."
      rman target / >> $rman_backup << EOF
         set echo on;
         configure retention policy to redundancy 2;
         configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk clear;
         configure controlfile autobackup on;
         sql "create pfile=''$rman_spfile2init'' from spfile";
         backup as backupset device type disk database;
         configure controlfile autobackup off;
         delete noprompt obsolete;
EOF
      if [ $? = 0 ]; then
         failed=false;
      else
         failed=true
         errstr="RMAN error: See log for details"
      fi;
      rman target / >> $rman_backup << EOF
         sql 'alter system archive log current';
EOF
      ;;

      \$NOARCHIVELOG\$)
      echo "Warning: Log archiving (ARCHIVELOG mode) is currently disabled. If"
      echo "you restore the database from this backup, any transactions that take"
      echo "place between this backup and the next backup will be lost. It is"
      echo "recommended that you enable ARCHIVELOG mode before proceeding so "
      echo "that all transactions can be recovered upon restore. See the section"
      echo "'Enabling ARCHIVELOG Mode...' in the online help for instructions."

      echo "Backup with log archiving disabled will shut down and restart the"
      echo -n "database. Are you sure [Y/N]?"
      gotit=false
      while ! $gotit; do
        read userinp
        if [ "$userinp" = "Y" -o "$userinp" = "y" -o \
             "$userinp" = "n" -o "$userinp" = "N" ]; then
          gotit=true
        fi
      done

      if [ "$userinp" = "n" -o "$userinp" = "N" ]; then
         rm -f $rman_backup
         exit -1;
      fi

      echo "Backup in progress..."

      rman target / >> $rman_backup << EOF
         set echo on; 
         shutdown immediate;
         startup mount;
         configure retention policy to redundancy 2;
         configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk clear;
         configure controlfile autobackup on;
         sql "create pfile=''$rman_spfile2init'' from spfile";
         backup as backupset device type disk database;
         configure controlfile autobackup off;
         alter database open;
         delete noprompt obsolete;
EOF
      if [ $? = 0 ]; then
         failed=false;
      else
         failed=true
         errstr="RMAN error: See log for details"
      fi;
      ;;

      *)
      errstr="Unknown database mode $mode"
      failed=true;
      ;;
   esac;
fi;

#Save the error string in the log
if [ $failed = 'true' ]; then
   echo ${errstr}. >> $rman_backup
fi;

#Save the last run as previous
if [ -f $rman_backup_current ]; then
   mv -f $rman_backup_current $rman_backup_prev
fi;

#Save the current run
mv -f $rman_backup $rman_backup_current

#Display the result to user
if [ $failed = 'true' ] ; then
   echo '==================== ERROR ========================='
   echo '             Backup of the database failed          '
   echo '==================== ERROR ========================='
   echo ${errstr}.
   echo Log file is at $rman_backup_current.
else
   echo Backup of the database succeeded.
   echo Log file is at $rman_backup_current.
   mail -s 'Oracle Backup Completed' 'email@gmail.com' < /var/oracle/ora_backup_script/oxe_backup_current.log
fi

#Wait for user to press any key
#echo -n "Press ENTER key to exit"
#read userinp
```

OR When Plesk is updating OR When I update any Plesk module manually.

My OS is CentOS release 6.7 (Final) and Oracle XE 11.2.0.2.0

Please advise. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: This is almost certainly a Linux kernel config problem. Did you set the kernel parameters as detailed in the pre-install checklist? (Number of open semaphores, SHMMAX etc)?

Comment: No. How can I set them? Please advise

Comment: "Configuring Kernel Parameters and Resource Limits"
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCCADGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is surely a resources or limits problem. 
For the first check if you have RemoveIPC enabled ([Man for login.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/logind.conf.5.html)

If it does not solve, review the [Database Quick Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm) in the sections [Configuring Kernel Parameters and Resource Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCCADGD) and [Creating Required Operating System Groups and Users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCBCFDI)

Regards
Giova